# IE addon to inject java script

Tags: internet-explorer, bho, browser-addons, ieaddon

I have successfully created extensions for chrome and Firefox that utilize content script to inject javascript.

What is the best way to accomplish the same thing for an IE add on?
The information I have found so far points to a bho written in c++ as .net has performance drawbacks.

I have extensive knowledge of .net but new to c++.

Any working example available with installer?

Answer (score 0):

I've build only one BHO in my life but let me share humble my experience. From my point of view C#/.Net/Managed BHO would be best for you. It will speed up the development and it will make harder to make something wrong in the code (like playing with memory or type casting). The only drawback that can be is the performance but I it depends on what kind of extension you're building.

To find examples of C#/.Net BHOs i think CodeProject site will be good enought - http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=bho+C%23&doctypeid=1%3b2%3b3%3b13%3b14.
Regarding installer - for my solution I was using Wix and it served me pretty good.